# Boot failure with samsung 850 evo msata installed in hp envy 15-100j

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, msata, hp-envy

I have windows 10 installed in my HP envy 15-100j. I have 1 tb harddisk with msata slot empty at the time I bought the laptop. Now I bought a new Samsung 850 evo msata ssd (250gb) and when I install the hardware and press the power button, I get windows 10 cannot boot with boot failure error message. But when I remove ssd windows 10 properly loads up. I am trying to follow this tutorial at [how to install on msata ssd boot drive in your laptop](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/install-msata-ssd-tutorial)

On the hp envy specs, I find that my laptop can have msata 32gb for cache purposes. On the tutorial, it says I can boot from msata ssd even though the main purpose of that slot is for cache in my laptop.

Comment: What *exact* error message do you see on boot?

Comment: No bootable device

Comment: Have you tried to select the HDD from the boot menu? I expect its trying to boot of the SSD